# Filling in data for a struct that holds an array of of pointers to a different struct

Tags: c, struct

In my code below there are two structs. One called person and one called person_list which holds by reference a list of person structs or 'people'.

I want to fill in (or reference) 10 person structs within person_list but upon running this code I am getting a segmentation fault. How can I handle or declare the memory for each person so this works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED 10

struct person_list {
    struct person *people[MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED];
};

struct person
{
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];
    //int age;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    struct person_list list;
    struct person pers[10];
    int i;
    char name[MAX_LENGTH];

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED; i++) {
        sprintf(descrip, "I am person number: %d", i);
        strcpy( &pers[i].name, name);
        list.people[i] = &pers[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: To fix your primary problem, you either need to remove the `*` or you need to allocate the space for each `struct person`.  As it stands, you're writing to uninitialized pointers, and crash is a common result when you do that (the behaviour is undefined and anything _could_ happen, but a crash is probable).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Do I have to put: list.people[i] = malloc (sizeof(person) + 1)? in the array?

Comment: There's no need for the +1, but yes, you need to allocate memory like that for each entry in the array.  You'll also need to sort out the `list.people[i] = &pers[i];` assignment; it should be a structure assignment `*list.people[i] = pers[i];`, and then you can debate about whether you need `pers` to be an array at all, and if it remains an array, the dimension should be MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED rather than just 10.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thankyou I managed to compile successfully the code.

Answer (score 0):

@BDillan ,I have made some simple corrections to your code, hope that you are looking for something similar to this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED 10

struct person_list {
struct person *people[MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED];
};

struct person
{
char name[MAX_LENGTH];
//int age;
};

int main()
{

struct person_list list;
struct person pers[10];
char descrip[MAX_LENGTH];
int i;
char name[MAX_LENGTH];

for (i = 0;i < MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED; i++)
 {
    sprintf(descrip, "I am person number: %d", i);
    strcpy(pers[i].name,descrip);
 //puts(pers[i].name);
   list.people[i] = &pers[i];
 }

 //to display the details of persions entered above

 for (i = 0;i < MAX_PEOPLE_ALLOWED; i++)
             printf("%s \n",list.people[i]->name);

 }
```